# jQuery element offset() returning incorrect values?

Tags: jquery, offset

I'm trying to get the correct offset value using foo.offset().top for the `<sup>` element that appears in the first paragraph of an article. Here's a screenshot of what I'm talking about:

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRBaN.png)

The red box is 377px from the top of the document, which is the computed value that offset() is returning. The problem is that I'm trying to find the offset for the first superscript element in the paragraph (where it begins "All children,"). Clearly something fishy is going on.

Any ideas? I'm unable to link to a live site since I'm developing locally for the time being.
(tested and having same trouble in both Chrome and Firefox)

Comment: `<sup>` is an `inline` element and that's why it returns unexpected values.

Comment: try `$('sup:first').offset()`

Comment: :first doesn't work. Oddly, it appears that assigning each `<sup>` a unique id might solve the problem -- I don't know if that's true for all inline elements using `offset()`. I'm not sure yet though, still toying with it.

Comment: there is a similar question, hope that it can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995838/left-offset-of-an-inline-element-using-jquery?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that question before and none of the solutions work for this problem. To be more specific, I'm iterating over each `<sup>` in the content using jQuery's `each()` function, so I should be isolating individual `<sup>` elements already. Also, inserting a block level element for measurement purposes still doesn't work.

Comment: can you provide a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: Hi guys, looks like assigning the `<sup>` a unique id value and running the query on that solves the problem. Very strange.

Comment: have you tried `eq()`?  `$('sup:eq(0)').offset()`?