# How to determine the actual position (left corner) of the span element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left offset of an inline element using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995838/left-offset-of-an-inline-element-using-jquery)

I have this HTML:

```
<div>hello <span>world<br/>
hello world</span></div>
```

Obviously, the span element starts not at the beginning in the first line and thus its shape is not exactly rectangular. However, if I use jQuery to get the position

```
$("div").offset().left === $("span").offset().left // is true
```

How can I determine the actual left-corner of the span?

Comment: What do you mean by `actual left corner position`?

Comment: I mean that if you set a background for this span, you'll see the background starts not at the beginning of the line, but with the word "hello". I basically want the position at which this word starts, whereas `offset().left` fot the span returns the beginning of the line position.

Comment: Yes, it's a duplicate. Thanks, this solves my problem.